# Parsing variables in strings like vBulletin

Tags: php, parsing, vbulletin, phrase

I'm not sure how else to put it.. 
What should I consider when attempting to "parse" variables in a string, such as vBulletin in phrases?

ex;

```
{username} you have two notifications
```

I've checker into smarty/raintpl, and have studied on some regex for all of this, smarty/raintpl are exactly what I need, the only problem is, they're both reading from files, I'm extracting from a database, I'm in need of something such as;

```
$username = "Bob";
$html = "{username} you have two notifications";
display($html);
```

If I use any replacing functions (regex/str_replace), will this slow the script / website down?

Comment: consider using a template engine that does this already. For example: http://www.smarty.net/ - but the variable syntax is a little different with smarty

Comment: If you're looking for a template system consider: Raintpl (http://www.raintpl.com/) has a very similar syntax: {$variable_name}

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple regex like:

```
$matches = array();

$string = '{username} you have two notifications';
preg_match_all('/{(\w+)}/', $string, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Which outputs:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => {username}
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => username
        )

)
```

Or if you wanted something a little more advanced:

```
$matches = array();

$string = '{username or something=3} you have two notifications';
preg_match_all('/{([^}]+)}/', $string, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Which similarly gives you:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => {username or something=3}
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => username or something=3
        )

)
```

I would suggest being as strict as you can - i.e. know exactly what you want to allow and only allow that (i.e. lowercase letters or numbers and spaces) - it will make it simpler in the long run.

There is the option to use external template engines, such as smarty, twig or dwoo, but depending on your project you may find this overkill.